# Wrap links in <a> tag with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to wrap all links in the text with "a" tag with regular expression in php, except those, who are already wraped

So i have text:

`Some text with html  here

http://www.somelink.html

http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=95

<a href="http://anotherlink.html">http://anotherlink.html</a>

<a href="http://anotherlink.html">Title</a>`

What i need to get:

`Some text with html  here

<a href="http://www.somelink.html">http://www.somelink.html</a>
<a href="http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=2495">http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=95</a>

<a href="http://anotherlink.html">http://anotherlink.html</a>

<a href="http://anotherlink.html">Title</a>`

I can match links with this expression:

`(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]`

but it matchs also thouse who are in "a" tags already

Comment: then maybe you should just watch if you have " around your link to define if you are already in <a> tag or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reliability, I would split on `<a>` tags (inclusive of child content) plus other tags (exclusive of child content) like:

```
$bits = preg_split('/(<a(?:\s+[^>]*)?>.*?<\/a>|<[a-z][^>]*>)/is', $content, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$reconstructed = '';

foreach ($bits as $bit) {
  if (strpos($bit, '<') !== 0) {//not inside an <a> or within < and > so check for urls
    $bit = link_urls($bit);
  }
  $reconstructed .= $bit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The syntax is:

```
(?<!text)
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
(?<!\<a)
```

Or something close to the above.

Comment: I'm trying this.. 
**(?<!<a\shref=".+?>)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]**
But it dosen't work. Can you be more specific?

Comment: PHP doesn't support variable-length lookbehinds. In this case, it should be fine, as the lookbehind is fixed-length.

Comment: Or at least, PHP didn't support variable-length lookbehinds 3 years ago. It may be available in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

The jist of the regex and replacement are below (in perl). Should be enough.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $html = '
  http://Top.html

  Some text with more html here
  <a href="http://www.somelink.html">
        http://www.somelink.html
  </a>

  <a href="http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=2495">
       http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=95
  </a>

  <a href="http://anotherlink.html">
       http://anotherlink.html
  </a>

  http://andone.html
  http://andtwo.html

  <a href="http://anthisisotherlink.html"><mn>
       Title
     http://this  <br>
       <b href="http://erlink.html">
     asdf
  </a> 
';

{
 no warnings;
 $html =~ 

 # Regex (global relace) ..
  s{(?is)
      (<   (?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--)
         | script\s[^>]*>.*?</script\s*
         | style\s[^>]*>.*?</style\s*
         | a\s[^>]*>.*?</a\s*
         | (?:/?\w+\s*/?|(?:\w+\s+(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+\s*/?))
        >
      )
    | ( (?:
         (?!(?:(?:https?|ftp)://|www.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])
         [^<]
        )*?
      )
    | ( (?:(?:https?|ftp)://|www.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|] )
  }

 # Replacement (would be a callback function in php) ..
  {
     defined $3 ? "<a href=\"$3\">$3</a>" : "$1$2"
  }xeg;
}

print $html,"\n";
```

Output

```
  <a href="http://Top.html">http://Top.html</a>

  Some text with more html here
  <a href="http://www.somelink.html">
        <a href="http://www.somelink.html">http://www.somelink.html</a>
  </a>

  <a href="http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=2495">
       http://www.somelink.com/view/?id=95
  </a>

  <a href="http://anotherlink.html">
       http://anotherlink.html
  </a>

  <a href="http://andone.html">http://andone.html</a>
  <a href="http://andtwo.html">http://andtwo.html</a>

  <a href="http://anthisisotherlink.html"><mn>
       Title
     http://this  <br>
       <b href="http://erlink.html">
     asdf
  </a>
```